# Why does this script resource not install Chocolatey packages?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, package-management

I'm trying to write a desired state configuration that installs a package via PackageManagement (aka OneGet). The package, "notepadplusplus", comes from the Chocolatey repository but I want to use PackageManagement rather than the Chocolatey client. I couldn't find a DSC resource to do it, so I'm using a Script resource.

DSC runs without errors and Notepad++ shows up in the packages list but never actually gets installed (`Notepad++.exe` is nowhere on the system).

I'm running on a Windows 10 VM.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing. Anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

*dscConfig.ps1*

```
Configuration BuildProvisioning
{
    param(
        [string[]]$computerName="localhost"
    )
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node $computerName
    {
        Script PackageManagementTest
        {
            SetScript = {
                Get-PackageProvider NuGet -Force | Out-Null
                Get-PackageProvider Chocolatey -Force | Out-Null
                Install-Package notepadplusplus -Force
            }
            TestScript = { $false }
            GetScript  = { @{} }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm kicking it off on the VM

```
. .\dscConfig.ps1
BuildProvisioning
winrm quickconfig -quiet
Start-DscConfiguration -Verbose -Force -Wait -ComputerName "localhost" -Path ".\BuildProvisioning\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by [this issue in OneGet](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/97#issuecomment-139331418), where you have to enable scrips via Set-ExecutionPolicy or OneGet fails while reporting success. This happens *even if you* set the execution policy before starting DSC. It has to be set within your DSC configuration. Apparently, it's running in a new session that doesn't inherit the execution policy.

Here's a simple fix where I set the execution policy before the package installation:

```
Configuration BuildProvisioning
{
    param(
        [string[]]$computerName="localhost"
    )
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node $computerName
    {
        Script ExecutionPolicy
        {
            SetScript = {
                Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
            }
            TestScript = { $false }
            GetScript  = { @{} }
        }

        Script PackageManagementTest
        {
            SetScript = {
                Get-PackageProvider NuGet -Force | Out-Null
                Get-PackageProvider Chocolatey -Force | Out-Null
                Install-Package notepadplusplus -Force
            }
            TestScript = { $false }
            GetScript  = { @{} }
            DependsOn = "[Script]ExecutionPolicy"
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using a Script resource to set the execution policy, you might try the [xPowerShellExecutionPolicy](https://github.com/PowerShell/xPowerShellExecutionPolicy) resource. [Install instructions here](http://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xPowerShellExecutionPolicy/) and [here's a sample DSC configuration](https://github.com/PowerShell/xPowerShellExecutionPolicy/blob/dev/Examples/SetPowerShellExecutionPolicy.ps1).